# SublimeCodeIntel does not recognize project .codeintel/config

Tags: python, sublimetext2, virtualenv, sublimecodeintel

I can get the `~/.codeintel/config` file (in the home directory) to be read and can delete the `db` to force SublimeCodeIntel to re-read it.  However, when I try to use the `<project_root>/.codeintel/config` (in the project root) SublimeCodeIntel does not build a new db / seem to read the files.

The SublimeCodeIntel project at Github [says](https://github.com/imanoleizaguirre/Sublime-Text-2-Plugins---Settings/tree/master/plugins/SublimeCodeIntel)

> Configuration files (~/.codeintel/config or project_root/.codeintel/config). All configurations are optional.

This is holding me up because I am using different versions of Python for my system and in my projects.  Certain modules that are available to one are not available in another, and those happen to be modules I'd like to use.  Anyone figure out how to get SublimeCodeIntel to read the `.codeintel/config` in the project root successfully?

So what's up with this?

Comment: First off, are you using the [official version](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) of SCI? Have you opened [an issue](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/new) with it? SCI recently released a new major version, so if this was a bug it may be fixed already...

Comment: Hi @MattDMo, yes - I am using 2.0.1 which appears to be the latest release. There is a ticket at https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/293 with no responses yet. Thanks!! Still hoping someone has figured this out and can help me out here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but turned out it was just a simpl misconfiguration

Opened my project in ST, picked `Project` -> `Save Project As...` to turn my directory into a ST project directory. (I saved the .sublime-project file in the same directory but this is just my preference)

Then created a .codeintel/config folder in the same directory with the following content:

```
{
    "Python": {
        "python": 'venv/bin/python',
        "pythonExtraPaths": ['venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',]
    }
}
```

(`venv` is my project's virtual env). Codeintel is successfully indexing my virtual environment, giving me definition lookups and using the python binary in my venv.

Using ST3 and latest CodeIntel.